# Finding the range of function from inequality involving derivatives of a function

Tags: calculus, analysis

> Suppose $f(x)$ is a twice differentiable function on $ \left[ a, b \right]$ such that $f(a) = f(b) = 0$ and
>
> $$x^2 \frac{d^2 f}{dx^2} + 4x \frac{df}{dx} + 2f > 0 $$ for all $ x \in (a,b)$
>
> A. $f$ is negative for all $x \in (a,b)$
>
> B. $f$ is positive for all $x \in (a,b)$
>
> C. $f(x)=0$ for exactly one $x \in (a,b)$
>
> D. $f(x)=0$ for at least two $x \in (a,b)$
>
> ISI UGA 7/18/2021

Observations that I have made so far:

There must be some $c \in \left[ a, b \right]$ such that $f'(c)=0$

For the inequality, I consider the quadratic $x^2 \frac{d^2 f}{dx^2} + 4x \frac{df}{dx} + 2f$, I find that it can be positive in this interval if and only if $\frac{d^2 f}{dx^2}<0$ (to find out why, consider seeing sign as we take limit to positive and negative infinity)

This means, the $c$ such that $f'(c)=0$ must maximize $f(x)$... one more I idea I had is to set the discriminant of quadratic in $x$ on left of inequality as greater than $0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$(x^2 f(x))''=(2x f(x)+x^2 f'(x))'=x^2 f''(x)+2x f'(x)+2f(x)+2xf'(x)=x^2 f''(x)+4x f'(x)+2f(x)>0$$
Thus, if $g(x)=x^2 f(x)$, then $g''(x)>0$.
Now, $g(a)=g(b)=0$. This means that for some $c \in (a,b)$, $g'(c)=0$ from Rolles MVT.

Hence, since $g'(x)$ is an increasing function, for $a<x<c$, $g'(x)<0$ which means that function $g$ initially decreases, reaches a minima and then increases to $g(b)=0$. So it is always negative in $(a,b)$. Hence, the same is true for $f$, as $x^2$ is always positive. So option $A$.